# InvalidOperationException for dropdown filter in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, filter, asp.net-core-mvc, unhandled-exception, invalidoperationexception

I have created a global dropdown filter on my navbar. I get the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.String', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Website.ViewModels.CardsViewModel.CardsViewModel'.
>
> <sub>Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object value)</sub>

Here is my code -

`FilterController.cs`:

- The `_cache.Set()` in *FilterController.cs* redirects the code to *PostController.cs* when I open the Post page in website. It is only then that my code gives error.

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string postCategory)
{
    var categoryLst = new List<string>();

    var categoryQry = from p in _context.Posts
                      orderby p.PostCategory 
                      select p.PostCategory;

    categoryLst.AddRange(categoryQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(categoryLst);

    var posts = from c in _context.Posts
                select c;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postCategory))
    {
        posts = posts.Where(x => x.PostCategory == postCategory);
    }

    _cache.Set("category", postCategory);
    ViewBag.PostCategory = postCategory;

    string url = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

    return Redirect(url);
}
```

`PostController.cs`:

- The `_cache.Set()` in *FilterController.cs* redirects the code here.
- I have edited the code below.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var CardPostVM = new CardsViewModel
    {
        PostCard = await _context.Posts.ToListAsync()
    };

    var cached = _cache.TryGetValue("category", out var postCategory);

    if (cached)
    {
        return View(postCategory);
    }

    return View(CardPostVM);
}
```

---

(Reference files):

Using _PartialLayout `_TopNavbar.cshtml` for my navbar. Here is the view for the dropdown filter:

```html
<!-- dropdown filter -->
<form class="ps-lg-5" asp-controller="Filter" asp-action="Index" id="category" method="get">
    <div class="input-group ps-lg-5">
        <select class="form-control shadow-none" name="postCategory" id="post-filter">
            <option>All</option>">
            @foreach (var item in cardsVM.PostCategories)
            {
                <!option value="@item.CategoryName"  @(item.CategoryName.ToString() == ViewBag.PostCategory?.ToString() ? "selected" : "")>@item.CategoryName</!option>
            }
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success shadow-none me-2" type="submit"><i class='bx bx-filter'></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`CardsViewModel.cs` (mentioned in the error):

```cs
public class CardsViewModel
{
    public List<PostModel>? PostCard { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Update** (Reference files):

`_Layout.cshtml` is where `_TopNavbar.cshtml` is mentioned.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Links-->
</head>

<body id="body-pd">

    <!--Top Nav bar-->
    <div>
        <partial name="~/Views/Shared/TopNavbar/_TopNavbar.cshtml" />
    </div>

    <!--Render Body-->
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <!--Links-->

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

This is a _PartialLayout file `_PostCards.cshtml` that includes **@model CardsViewModel**:

```
@using RecipeWebsite.ViewModels.CardsViewModel

@model CardsViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.PostCard)
{
    // Detail of Card where my data is displayed
    <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
            <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" src="@item.Image" width="157" height="236" alt="Card image cap">

            <!--Card Details-->
            <div class="card-body">
                <a asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="stretched-link"></a>
                <h6 class="card-text"> @item.Title </h6>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
                    <p class="small text-secondary">@item.PostCategory</p>
                </div>            
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div> 
}
```

File where `PostCards.cshtml` is mentioned

```html
@using RecipeWebsite.ViewModels.CardsViewModel

@model CardsViewModel

<main>

    <!-- Cards -->
    @if (Model.PostCard.Count != 0)
    {
        <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">

                    <partial name="~/Views/Shared/Cards/_PostCards.cshtml" />

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else 
    {
        // Error
    }

</main>
```

---

Thank you

Comment: All of that logic in your `Index` action doesn't do anything because you're returning a Redirection instead of a View.

Comment: Post your `.cshtml` where you render your `_Partial Layout.cshtml` file.

Comment: @Dai I have updated `_Layout.cshtml` file

Comment: That error message will only be thrown if you have a `.cshtml` file with `@model CardsViewModel` - please post that file.

Comment: @Dai I have updated `_PostCards.cshtml` file that includes **@model CardsViewModel**

Comment: According to the error message, you are passing the string to view which requires  CardsViewModel. I reproduced the problem when getting the post/index if cached. The action that returns to your last view calling  PostCards.cshtml is not shown, please check if the string is passed.

Comment: @Ronaldoz The `_cache.Set()` in _FilterController.cs_ redirects the code to _PostController.cs_. The string gets passed to `return View(postCategory);` correctly.

Comment: @Dai The `_cache.Set()` in _FilterController.cs_ redirects the code to _PostController.cs_ when I open the Post page in website. It is only then that my code gives error.

Comment: @Ronaldoz It was my mistake. The code in my _FilterController.cs_ was incorrect resulting in error. Now that I have corrected my code, the **string** that is passed by `_cache.Set()` is being initialized incorrectly resulting in new but similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Here is my answer

- Change required in `FilterController.cs` and `PostController.cs`

`FilterController.cs`:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string postCategory)
{
    var filteredPost = from p in _context.Posts select p;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postCategory))
    {
        ViewBag.PostCategory = postCategory;

        filteredPost = filteredPost.Where(p => p.PostCategory == postCategory);
    }

    var filteredCategory = new CardsViewModel
    {
        PostCard = await filteredPost.ToListAsync()
    };

    _cache.Set("filteredCategory", filteredCategory);

    string url = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

    return Redirect(url);
}
```

PostController.cs

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var CardPostVM = new CardsViewModel
    {
        PostCard = await _context.Posts.ToListAsync()
    };

    var cached = _cache.TryGetValue("filteredCategory", out var filteredCategory);
    if (cached)
    {
        return View(filteredCategory);
    }

    return View(CardPostVM);
}
```